# Change layout xml and working Activity in Android app

Tags: java, android, xml

I have 2 Activities, MainActivity.java and OtherActivity.java. 
According to the Activities I have activity_main.xml and activity_other.xml layouts.

The starting Activity is the MainActivity.java with main.xml. 
I want a menu to swap the active activity and layout to the other. 
I tried it with sharedPreferences and activate the other but it didn't work for me.

Comment: you want to switch layout from portrait to landscape?

Comment: I have a WebView in my App. in one activity there are 2 buttons two navigate. and the 2 buttons are also in the xml.  But in the other activity there is a seekbar to navigate and the seekbar is also in the other xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use code below to start another activity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, OtherActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Use below to let one activity only have one instance.

```
<activity 
...
android:launchMode="singleInstance" >
...
```

Comment: So I have to make another button listener. And if its clicked it starts the other  activity, overwriting the First one ? and the XML has to be only one .XML ?

Comment: Er, why only one XML? You can have two, and in each activity's onCreate, load its own XML. By the way, it is true that you need 2 buttons.

Comment: I used the Intent code and its working, but i have 2 Icons of the App in App -menu now.

Comment: @omyholw Would you mind pasting your code of <activity ...> here? I think you add one wrong line to the OtherActivity.

Comment: I solved it in another way, I use one Activity and one xml and use a boolean which can be switched to false and true to change the used code out of Activity and show only buttons or seekbar out of the xml.